# ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver Error on Android Studio

Tags: java, sql-server, database, android-studio, connection

I am using Android Studio to make program.I tried to connect to database of SQL Server 2014. But I found *net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver* error. I do not know where I was missing or wrong
[image]
This is my code

```
private static final String LOG = "DEBUG";
private static String ip = "192.168.3.85";
private static String port = "1434";
private static String Driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
private static String db = "Work";
private static String un = "zom";
private static String password = "111111";
public void  connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    String query;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        Class.forName(Driver);
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip +":"+port+";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";
        query="  SELECT [Production order] FROM TIMEDATA1 WHERE  RecordID = (SELECT MAX (RECORDID ) FROM TIMEDATA1 WHERE [Resource] = ? )";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
         stmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
         stmt.setString(1,"M-MP3");
         rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            String result = rs.getString(1);
           mTextMessage.setText(result);
            Log.d("My Custom Tag", result);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.d("Error 1", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Error 2", e.getMessage());
    }


}
```